# How can I keep the content of one environment with the next paragraph from another environment on the same page?

Tags: environments, page-breaking, minipage

I am working with environments to be able to easily format the content of a document.

Now I want to define a rule so that the content from the `ccetheme` environment appears on the same page as the content from the next environment: it can be `ccebody`   or `ccesection`

I have seen that it can be done with `needspace` or `minipage`, but I can't do it.

This is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}
\setstocksize{9in}{6in}
\settrimmedsize{9in}{6in}{*}
\setbinding{0.5in}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.5in}{0.4in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.5in}{0.5in}{*}
\setheadfoot{12.07pt}{\footskip}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\headerfont{Libertinus Sans}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{needspace}  
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[showframe, pass]{geometry}
\newcommand{\txtred}{\textcolor{red}}
\newcommand\n[1]{\txtred{\textbf{#1}}}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------- CCE styles
\newenvironment{ccetheme}[1]{%
    % \begin{cr}{#1}
    \nopagebreak
    \par% Start a new paragraph
    \addvspace{\baselineskip}% Space above
    \centering% Alignment
    \bfseries% Weight
    \color{red}% Colour
    {\large #1\par}% Change to \LARGE or \Huge
    \ignorespaces
}
{% \end{cr}
    \par% Start a new paragraph
    \addvspace{\baselineskip}% Space below
    %\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    
    %\end{minipage}  
}

%Títulos en negrita del propio CCE
\newenvironment{ccesection}{%
    % \begin{cr}{#1}
    \par% Start a new paragraph
    \addvspace{\baselineskip}% Space above
    \bfseries% Weight
    \ignorespaces
}
{% \end{cr}
    \par% Start a new paragraph
    \addvspace{\baselineskip}% Space below
}

\newenvironment{ccebody}{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth} 
        %\textit{redtext}\
        %\fontfamily{gentium}\selectfont            
    \end{minipage}  
}%
{% \end{cr}
    %\nopagebreak
    %\par% Start a new paragraph
    %\addvspace{\baselineskip}% Space below
}

\newenvironment{ccecite}{%
    % \begin{cr}{#1}
    \par% Start a new paragraph
    \addvspace{\baselineskip}% Space above
    \alterfont% Font
    \ignorespaces
    \leftskip1cm\relax
    \rightskip1cm\relax
}
{% \end{cr}
    \par% Start a new paragraph
    \addvspace{\baselineskip}% Space below
}

\begin{document}
    \section{Temas}
    \begin{ccetheme}{La Alianza con Noé} {CEC 56-58, 71}\end{ccetheme}
    
    \begin{ccebody}
        \n{56} \lipsum[1-3] 
    \end{ccebody}   

    \begin{ccetheme}{Test} {CEC NNNN}\end{ccetheme}

    \begin{ccebody}
        \n{57} \lipsum[1-3] 
    \end{ccebody}   

    \begin{ccebody}
        \n{58} \lipsum[5] 
    \end{ccebody}

    \begin{ccebody}
        \n{59} \lipsum[6-8] 
    \end{ccebody}

    \begin{ccetheme}{Test} {CEC MMMM}\end{ccetheme}

    \begin{ccebody}
        \begin{ccesection}This is title on bold\end{ccesection}
        \n{59} \lipsum[1-3] 
    \end{ccebody}   
    
    \begin{ccebody}
        \n{60} \lipsum[5] 
    \end{ccebody}
    
\end{document}
```

As you can see in the images below, in this particular case there is an unpleasant cut between the `ccetheme` environment and the `ccebody` environment.

[image]

Also in this case, where I use the ccesection environment I would like the content of ccetheme along with the following to go to the next page:

[image]

**I want to know if there is any way to force `ccetheme` content to always appear on the same page as the next paragraph**.

As you can see, to achieve this I am putting `\nopagebreak` in `ccetheme` environment and trying to implement `minipage` in `ccebody`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: There are three ways to keep certain things together.  The first is to put both inside an unbreakable box, like a minipage.  The second is to compute how much space is needed and use the needspace package.  The third is to max out the penalty for page breaking between the two (see \@afterheading).

Comment: @JohnKormylo But how could I do it from the environments? It is a very long document and I would like to do this automatically. Is that possible?

Comment: you haven't provided any usable test code so hard to answer but adding `\nopagebreak` after the `\par` in `ccetheme` probably does something

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. Doing that works best. I think if I manage to make the `ccebody` paragraphs stick together on the same page it would work as I hope. Is there a way to indicate that in the ccebody environment? Sorry for not giving a complete example, the text is too long.

Comment: you can use packages like lipsum to generate dummy paragraphs while keeping the example short. if your ccebody never needs to break over a page (so is never longer than a page for example) you can use a minipage in its definition. a minipage never breaks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added a minimal example and what I have tried in the environments without success.

Comment: your minipages are all empty it seems?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm new in LaTeX, i don't know how I can indicate that `ccebody` is a `minipage`, sorry.

Comment: do you ever have content in your ccetheme environment? `\begin{ccetheme}{La Alianza con Noé} {CEC 56-58, 71}\end{ccetheme}`  looks rather odd it would be more natural like `\section`  a command taking atguments `\ccetheme{La Alianza con Noé} {CEC 56-58, 71}` unless theer are cases where you use the environment body?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In `ccetheme` I always have those two data, I use the environment to put them in red and to put it one below the other and I would eventually use it to change the font of the second argument, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This still has a few warnings and spacing could be tweaked but something like this I think is closer to what you want

also use commands when there is fixed number of braced arguments and environments when you need to surround larger chunks of text.

[image]

```
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}
\setstocksize{9in}{6in}
\settrimmedsize{9in}{6in}{*}
\setbinding{0.5in}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.5in}{0.4in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.5in}{0.5in}{*}
\setheadfoot{12.07pt}{\footskip}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\headerfont{Libertinus Sans}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{needspace}  
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[showframe, pass]{geometry}
\newcommand{\txtred}{\textcolor{red}}
\newcommand\n[1]{\txtred{\textbf{#1}}}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------- CCE styles
\newcommand{\ccetheme}[2]{%
\def\cceA{#1}%
\def\cceB{#2}%
}
%Títulos en negrita del propio CCE
\newcommand{\ccesection}[1]{%
    \par% Start a new paragraph
    \addvspace{\baselineskip}% Space above
    \noindent\textbf{#1}%
    \par
}


\newenvironment{ccebody}{%
    \par% Start a new paragraph
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
    \setlength\parindent{15pt}%
    \ifx\cceA\relax\else
    \begin{center}
    \bfseries% Weight
    \color{red}% Colour
    \large \cceA\\\cceB
    \end{center}%
    \fi
    \global\let\cceA\relax
    \par
}%
{\end{minipage}%
\par}

\newenvironment{ccecite}{%
    % \begin{cr}{#1}
    \quote
    \alterfont% Font
}
{\endquote
}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
    \section{Temas}
    \ccetheme{La Alianza con Noé} {CEC 56-58, 71}
    
    \begin{ccebody}
        \n{56} \lipsum[1-3] 
    \end{ccebody}   

    \ccetheme{Test} {CEC NNNN}

    \begin{ccebody}
        \n{57} \lipsum[1-3] 
    \end{ccebody}   

    \begin{ccebody}
        \n{58} \lipsum[5] 
    \end{ccebody}

    \begin{ccebody}
        \n{59} \lipsum[6-8] 
    \end{ccebody}

    \ccetheme{Test} {CEC MMMM}

    \begin{ccebody}
        \ccesection{This is title on bold}
        \n{59} \lipsum[1-3] 
    \end{ccebody}   
    
    \begin{ccebody}
        \n{60} \lipsum[5] 
    \end{ccebody}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to work as expected. Thank you.

Comment: With this code I have lost the indentation in the first line of each paragraph of `ccebody`, do you know how I could recover it?

Comment: stick `\setlength\parindent{15pt}` (or whatever) just after `\begin{minipage}`

Comment: Addint this: `\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
  \setlength\parindent{15pt}` is working only after 2nd paragraph, not indenting the 1st paragraph.

Comment: @A.Cedano should work, I added a picture unless I missed something (I also stopped the heading indenting with \noindent)

Comment: David thanks for you help. But it's not working. If you see this block, `\n{56} \lipsum[1-3]` it's not indenting. I'm having issues with the bottom margin too. For example, if I do this: `\n{56} \lipsum[1-29]`  the text overflows bottom margin (maybe this is the subject of a new question).

Comment: I'll look at indent in a bit, for the bottom margin, well I did ask at the start if it would always fit. minipage prevents page breaking so the content  of each ccebody plus a possible title will always be kept together it has to fit. If you need it to sometimes break over a page then the minipage solution is not what you need. But you need to say where you want to stop breaks, just after the red heading? In that case my initial `\nopagebreak` comment is probably all you need.

Comment: What I need is that when `ccetheme` and `ccebody`  (or `ccesection`) do not enter the same page, they both go to the next page. This is something like "keep together with next paragraph" in the usual text editors.

Comment: indent fixed \par added at end of the start code

Comment: yes but do you mean theme and body do not fit go togethe to next page (thats what I implemented) or theme and first line of body stay together (that would b ethe nopagebreak comment) or that no page breaks are allowed in the first paragraph of ccebody which also has to stay with the section. or .. This implements "ccetheme and following ccebody are always on same page" where always means always even if ccebody is 1000 lines long. If that's not OK that's fins, but this answer isn't fixale you need a different answer

Comment: Yes, indent is fixed. The bottom margin issue persists. There is no way to force a jump to the next page for paragraphs that overflow the bottom margin?

Comment: I think it is better to take this part for solved and open a new question where I can better explain the new problem.

Comment: well not really since the only purpose of minipage is to prevent page breaking so if you have a need for a page break, the answer is "don't start from here" ie use a different technique to solve the original question.